# Postgres connection frequently closed/reopened

Tags: postgresql, go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-proxy

I am seeing frequently connection close and open messages for every request on the file upload process.

One of the articles I found was asking to set open/idle connections but it not working error message still coming.

What will be case I am not able to find what's going on so attaching data `database.go` code and dog log screen.

```golang
func InitDatabase(ctx context.Context, opts infrastructure.DBOptions) (Database, error) {
    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s dbname=%s user=%s sslmode=disable",
        opts.Host,
        opts.Database,
        opts.User,
    )

    if opts.Pass != "" {
        dsn = fmt.Sprintf("%s password=%s", dsn, opts.Pass)
    }

    sqltrace.Register("postgres", &pq.Driver{})
    db, err := sqltrace.Open("postgres", dsn)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Retrieve the value of "MaxOpenConns" and "MaxIdleConns" from opts
    defaultMaxIdleConns := 100
    defaultMaxOpenConns := 100

    // Convert the string to an integer
    maxIdleConns, err := strconv.Atoi(opts.MaxIdleConns)

    if err != nil {
        // Handle the error if conversion fails
        db.SetMaxIdleConns(defaultMaxIdleConns)
    } else {
        // Set maximum number of connections in idle connection pool.
        db.SetMaxIdleConns(maxIdleConns)
    }

    // Convert the string to an integer
    maxOpenConns, err := strconv.Atoi(opts.MaxOpenConns)

    if err != nil {
        // Handle the error if conversion fails
        db.SetMaxOpenConns(defaultMaxOpenConns)
    } else {
        // Set the maximum number of open connections to the database.
        db.SetMaxOpenConns(maxOpenConns)
    }

    db.SetConnMaxLifetime(time.Hour)

    database := &DocumentDatabase{
        DB: db,
    }

    log.Info().Caller().Msgf("initialized db host: %v | database: %v", opts.Host, opts.Database)
    return database, nil
}
```

[image: datadog log]

Comment: So what setting is actually being used for `SetMaxIdleConns` and `SetMaxOpenConns` (is it the defaults you are setting, or is something else being passed in via `opts`?). Please show us a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) i.e. hardcode the timeout values, show us how you connect, and include a sample use of the database in your example code.

Comment: Default connections  idle/open i added temporary to identify if we can get a read of frequent connection drop error but i cant. default connection count which i am using will be passed from manifest.

followed below document suggestions
https://go.dev/doc/database/manage-connections

Comment: That does not really answer my question; without more info it's not really possible to answer yours (you have not shown us how/when the connection is opened or used). The default for `MaxIdleConns` is 2; you can easily exceed this number of connections by running multiple queries concurrently.

Comment: Hi, 
I have already attached the full Database connection code file. Where I am passing all required opts from the terraform manifest by generating env variables.
`code`
TImeout is one hour in the  line. db.SetConnMaxLifetime(time.Hour)
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ generating on load and passing database file as 'opts'+++++++++++++++

Comment: DB: DBOptions{
   Host:     os.Getenv("POSTGRES_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME"),
   Database: os.Getenv("POSTGRES_DATABASE_NAME"),
   User:     os.Getenv("POSTGRES_DATABASE_USER"),
   Pass:     os.Getenv("POSTGRES_PASSWORD"),
   MaxOpenConns:     os.Getenv("MAX_OPEN_DB_CONNS"),
   MaxIdleConns:     os.Getenv("MAX_IDLE_DB_CONNS"),
  },
`code`

Comment: Are you sure that the connection closures are due to the pool manager? (what is the trace showing?) Here is an alternative possibility; file upload request comes in, you run `QueryContext` (with the request context), you neglect to close the `Rows`, context is then cancelled which can lead to the connection dropping (this is driver dependent).

Comment: My 2 cents: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." Does the connection management cause any *real* problems? As long as this is not the case (and I HIGHLY doubt that it ever will be), it should be none of your concern.